# ActiveRecord::QueryMethods not working within rspec test but in console it working fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

### I have a test where I want to test that a book_group cannot delete when is associated with a book, this test failed but in the application, this feature works fine

```
describe 'callbacks' do
context 'before_validation' do
  include_examples 'examples for strippable attributes', :book_group, :name, :description, :spawn_button_label
end

it 'is not destroyed and returns a base error if there is an book associated to the it' do
  error = 'Cannot delete record because dependent books exist'
  book_group.books << create(:book)
  expect(book_group.destroy).to be false
 end
end
```

### I debugged into the test and found that the error is because this query not working as expected

- First, I valid that these two models have an association

> ```
> pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::bookGroup::Callbacks>)> book_group.books 
> => [#<book:0x0000563cb3f6eaf0
> id: 1,
> review_id: 1,
> name: "Vernie Becker",
> level: "site",
> book_group_id: 831812,
> author_book_id: nil]
> ```

- I do the next query but its result is wrong

> book_group.books.where(author_book_id: nil).order(id: :desc).first
> => nil

### but this query within console working as expected

```
[4] pry(main)> @book_group.books.where(author_book_id: nil).order(id: :desc).first DEBUG 

[2022-04-02T16:16:49.295Z]   book Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `books`.* FROM `books` WHERE `books`.`book_group_id` = 6 AND `books`.`author_book_id` IS NULL ORDER BY `books`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<book:0x000055d2217339c8  id: 261,  review_id: 1,  name: "Base book site",  level: "site",  book_group_id: 6,  book_template_id: 2,  author_book_id: nil]
```

### the book_group is created in this way

```
def create
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    @book_group = bookGroup.new(book_group_params)
    @book_group.author_id = params[:author_id]
    @book_group.save!
    AllowedActorship.create_from_level_scoped_params(
    book_group_params,
    @book_group
    )
    render(
    json: { message: @book_group },
    status: :ok
    )
  end
end
```

#### I already have reset and prepared the bd, I'm not sure why it working so weird, I will say thank you for whatever helped with it.

Comment: Can you show how book_group is created? it cant be a new record

Comment: @JoelBlum sure, I've edited the question including the create method, thanks

Comment: Sorry didn't explain myself well - how it's created in the spec?

Comment: @JoelBlum it's created in the "context block" in "include_examples"

Comment: can you inspect `book_group` in the test. looks like it's not persisted. you have the `book_group` object, but not in the database. if that's not it, can you show how you create `book_group` in the test itself, not the controller. `include_examples` is only available inside `before_validation` context; `it` block is outside of that context.